# IndentationError: expected an indented block, python (if/else)

Tags: python

**I can't find the error**

```
def free_car(lane_a,lane_b,lane_c):
    cars_a = len(lane_a)
    cars_b = len(lane_b)
    cars_c = len(lane_c)

    if cars_c >= 7:
        #free_1_c
        if cars_a >= cars_b:
            #free_1_a
            #free_1_b
        else:
            #free_1_b
            #free_1_a
    elif cars_a >= cars_b:
        #free_1_a
        if cars_b > cars_c:
            #free_1_b
            #free_1_c
        else:
            #free_1_c
            #free_1_b
    elif cars_b > cars_a and cars_b > cars_c:
        #free_1_b
        if cars_a > cars_c:
            #free_1_a
            #free_1_c
        else:
            #free_1_c
            #free_1_a
    else:
        #we
```

The error starts on the line 11 (on the else after cars_c >= 7) I know its a stupid error and question but i can't figure it out why the error it's there

Comment: You're not indenting the code in `free_car()`.

Comment: sorry, the page move the tabs order, but it is idented everything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a block like this:

```
if cars_a >= cars_b:
    #free_1_a
    #free_1_b
else:
    #free_1_b
    #free_1_a
```

Since both `free_1_a` and `free_1_b` are commented out, they are effectively empty to python. It is illegal.

You can resolve it by adding `pass`

i.e.

```
if cars_a >= cars_b:
    #free_1_a
    #free_1_b
    pass
else:
    #free_1_b
    #free_1_a
    pass
```

`pass` basically means 'no operation'

Answer (score 0):

Python requires a statement after each clause.  If you want it to do nothing, simply write the word `pass`

```
if cars_c >= 7:
    #free_1_c
    if cars_a >= cars_b:
        pass
        #free_1_a
        #free_1_b
    else:
        pass
        #free_1_b
        #free_1_a
elif cars_a >= cars_b:
    #free_1_a
    if cars_b > cars_c:
        pass
        #free_1_b
        #free_1_c
    else:
        pass
        #free_1_c
        #free_1_b
elif cars_b > cars_a and cars_b > cars_c:
    #free_1_b
    if cars_a > cars_c:
        pass
        #free_1_a
        #free_1_c
    else:
        pass
        #free_1_c
        #free_1_a
else:
    pass
    #we
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have comments inside those if and else blocks. That's not syntactically valid; you need an executable statement of some kind. You can use `pass` if there's nothing better, although in real code it's usually preferable to refactor so that the empty block isn't necessary.